# Azure Devops- Progress Reports- How to remove failed runs after they are fixed, rerun and passed?

Tags: azure-devops

Currently we are using Azure Devops for our manual test plans.
Testers run the steps manually if a step fails they assign a bug and move to the next test. test is deemed failed
Once the bug is fixed they rerun the test and it passes.

When I go to run the progress report it still shows as one failed test along with the newly passed test.
Is there a way to only show the most current run results?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only show the most current run results?

The [Progress Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops#behavior) will show the latest test result in the Summary. Since the data processing for this report is occurring approximately every **15 mins**. We need to wait for the update.

In addition, we could create Chart to show the latest test results.

Steps: Open test plan->click the tab Chart->create new test result chart->configure the field chart type and Group by(set to Outcome), then we could see the current run results.

Update1

The step is open test plan->select one suit and click the chart button to create chart, It just shows the results of a test suit.

If you need to show one test plan result, we could create widget to show it.

Steps:

Open Dashboards->add widget Chart for test Plans->configure test plan and test suit(select all test suit, check the pic below)->select chart for `Test results` and Group by outcome, then you could check one test plan result in this widget.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vito Liu-MSFT!!          Is there away to do all the folders under one suite?  When I try at the top level it is only picking up a few but not all?

Comment: Hi @Sandy, I have updated the answer, you could check it and kindly share the result here. By the way, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @Sandy, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @Sandy, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?